# Homepage + redirect value from GET parameter

Tags: .htaccess

I need open `file.php` as index on my website. On homepage will be opened `file.php` without redirect to `www.website.com/file.php`

Second rewrite rule is redirect `www.website.com/?id={id}` to `www.website.com/{id}`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ file.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^$ /file.php

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?id=([^&]*)(&.*)?$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2%3
```

Help me with htaccess code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?id=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^$ /file.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ file.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: ```RewriteRule ^ page/%1? [R=301,L,NE]``` --> ```RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,NE]```

...but it is exactly what I needed

Comment: Yes, sorry that `/page` was a typo as I was testing it on my local apache.

Comment: Its okay, I know immediately where is "problem" - just correction :)